# How to set db model fields to just read-only even a superuser should be able to edit it

Tags: python, django, django-models

I tried this way like we do with `primary keys`
But it's not working they as I want.
I want Some fields to not editable from `Django Admin` We can manage it with permissions but I want it for all even superuser shouldn't be able to change values

I tried this way

`#models.py`

```
class Payments(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, verbose_name="Payment Made By",)
    paymentForOrderID = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True,editable=False, verbose_name="Payment For Order ID")
    paymentMethodUsed = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Method Used")
    aproxTimeAndDateOfPayment = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True,editable=False, verbose_name="Approx Date/Time Of Payment")
    totalAmountPaid = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True,editable=False, verbose_name="Amount Paid")
    paymentDetails = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True,editable=False,verbose_name="Details")
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    _id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True,editable=False, verbose_name="Entry ID")

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.createdAt)
```

Doing this when I open it it only shows editable fields but not the others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be some better way to do that but as far I think. ....
If you want to read non editable fields you can manage it from `admin.py` adding `list_display`
In your case keep the models same as it is ....

```
#models.py
class Payments(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, verbose_name="Payment Made By",)
    paymentForOrderID = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True,editable=False, verbose_name="Payment For Order ID")
    paymentMethodUsed = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Method Used")
    aproxTimeAndDateOfPayment = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True,editable=False, verbose_name="Approx Date/Time Of Payment")
    totalAmountPaid = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True,editable=False, verbose_name="Amount Paid")
    paymentDetails = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True,editable=False,verbose_name="Details")
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    _id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True,editable=False, verbose_name="Entry ID")

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.createdAt)
```

but add a `PaymentManager` in `admin.py`

your `admin.py` should be like

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Payments


class PaymentsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['_id','user', 'paymentForOrderID', 'paymentMethodUsed','aproxTimeAndDateOfPayment','totalAmountPaid','createdAt','paymentDetails']
    ordering = ['createdAt']

admin.site.register(Payments, PaymentsAdmin)
```

This way you can read values from list view but when you open it non-editable fields won't show.

Comment: yes it's working this way, is there any other way to do that ?

Comment: this can be trouble when values are much bigger ?